# Javascript function faster than the plain operation

Tags: javascript, performance, function, addition

I compare here an addition operation in plain JavaScript versus an function that does the same thing. The instance where this operation is encapsulated in a JavaScript function executes faster then the plain operation. What am i doing wrong in this comparison?

https://jsperf.com/in-function-operators#comment-form

Comment: this is the wrong way to approach benchmarking and understanding the compiler in general. before you can make any sense of these results, you need to understand how to write proper benchmarks.

Comment: Add a comment with at least 600 characters to the function and test again - you won't believe what happens next!

Comment: It is also not one compiler, Because different browsers have different results. Just found it curious. I wanted to know if i can use functions in js without huge performance penalties. I see what i did wrong, With using constants chrome noticed it and somehow optimized the function. I added random numbers and those perform almost the same. (In chrome that is)

Answer (score 3):

When I run the microbenchmarks, they all performed withing 1%/2% of each other so really for all intents and purposes they are perform the same (i.e. margin of error here).

The answer for why they perform roughly the same is that the JavaScript [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) has decided that the function should be [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function), thereby making its performance similar to the plain operation. In some situations, the JIT can even identify that you are adding two constants together and just replace the code with a straight up [assignment operation instead](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) (there is a note in there about how Uglify will replace 1+2*3 with 7, a JIT compiler will perform the same operation if it can identify it).